# Joomla Fabrik List element not clickable

Tags: joomla4

Joomla433 - Fabrik4delta
I created a list that contains an element src (type text)
This element src contains an URL (link to peertube videos)
In the list I created a calc field to generate a iframe tag with the source attribut = the value of src
When displaying the list I can see the calculated field (showing an image of the peertube video, but its not clickable.
Only when I click to get the detail view of the line of the list, I can click on the image.

Is there a way to make the image on the list clickable - I don't want to give access to the frontend user to go in the detaiml view. The frontend user should only be capable to play a video